# View Adobe AIR application directory on Android via USB

Tags: android, air

I have an Android device (Samsung Galaxy phone) connected to a PC via USB. I installed my AIR app and need to see some files that it creates. Is it possible to open the `/data/data/air.<APP ID>` directory in Windows Explorer? I enabled hidden files in folder options, but still can't see that directory.

Is it completely hidden by Android or there is any way to view it?

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible you're confusing files on the host (Windows, PC) and files on the Android device?
That path - `/data/data/air.<APP_ID>` looks like a device on the Android device, so it will not show up on the host (PC) file system (=Windows Explorer).
What you need is use some kind of utility to view the **Android** file system.

Without rooting the device, I think the best option is to use an Android app that acts as a File Explorer, like these:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mhoffs.filemanager&hl=en
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop&hl=en

Comment: I tried ES File Explorer File Manager before posting this question and it didn't show that directory. Yes, I understand that Android has a totally different file system.

Comment: Yes, wasn't sure, some people are confused by it (you also said "Windows Explorer"), that's why I only asked if it's possible. Did Inka File Manager work for you? I really like that one.

Comment: Well, I would really like to see those directories in Windows Explorer or perhaps some specialized Windows program. I'll try the Inka within a few hours and post an update.

Comment: ok, but Inka is on the device. I think for a Windows application to access that you'll need either a rooted device or use AirDroid: http://www.airdroid.com/ (which is cool anyway).

Comment: When trying to open /data in Inka File Manager, it shows "you don't have permission to read this file or folder". Clarification: I would prefer to get to that directory via Windows, but an on-device file manager would be also acceptable. I will check out airdroid.com. Seems interesting.

Comment: Tried AirDroid. Cool concept, but doesn't show anything inside the /data directory.

Comment: Sounds like an awesome device :p which one is it? Maybe it's device specific?

Comment: Samsung Galaxy 2 and Kindle Fire. I think this is how Android is set up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56603/discussion-between-snowdragon-and-user1566515).